# Referencing Number Named Object Inside Object

Tags: javascript

How do I get information from a number named object inside another object?

I have tried `console.log(obj.6.4)` but it does not work.

This is my object:

```
var obj = {
    0: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    1: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    2: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    3: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    4: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    5: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    6: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:'hi', 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    7: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    8: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
    9: {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
console.log(obj[6][4]);
```